VPC and Public Subnet Provisioning using CDK
I am trying to create two public subnet, with one route table. I that one route table to have two subnet association that is the two public subnet. I have explicitly kept subnetConfiguration: [], empty, to avoid any auto creation of subnet, and route table. The following is my code, yet the behavior isn't expected. Yet my CDK code creates two public subnet with two route table. I want two public subnet, that is associated with one route table. My CDK code is below, what am I doing wrong?
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class DevVpcStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create the VPC
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'DevVPC', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      subnetConfiguration: [], // Do not create any subnets automatically
      enableDnsHostnames: true,
      enableDnsSupport: true,
    });

    // Create public subnets
    const publicSubnet1 = new ec2.CfnSubnet(this, 'PublicSubnet1', {
      vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
      cidrBlock: '10.0.1.0/24',
      availabilityZone: cdk.Stack.of(this).availabilityZones[0],
      mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true,
    });

    const publicSubnet2 = new ec2.CfnSubnet(this, 'PublicSubnet2', {
      vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
      cidrBlock: '10.0.2.0/24',
      availabilityZone: cdk.Stack.of(this).availabilityZones[1],
      mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true,
    });

    // Create a single route table
    const routeTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, 'PublicRouteTable', {
      vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
    });

    // Associate the subnets with the route table
    new ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(this, 'PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation', {
      subnetId: publicSubnet1.ref,
      routeTableId: routeTable.ref,
    });

    new ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(this, 'PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation', {
      subnetId: publicSubnet2.ref,
      routeTableId: routeTable.ref,
    });
  }
}


Related: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3604

@jarmod is it? They're using CfnSubnet here, not Subnet.

You say this creates two Route tables - is that including the one you're creating explicitly with CfnRouteTable?

It created two RouteTables because VPC comes with a default 'main' RouteTable + the RouteTable you created.

I ran your CDK code but in Python:
vpc = ec2.Vpc(
    self, 'vpc',
    subnet_configuration=[]
)

pubsub1 = ec2.CfnSubnet(
    self, 'PublicSubnet1',
    vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
    cidr_block='10.0.1.0/24',
    map_public_ip_on_launch=True
)

pubsub2 = ec2.CfnSubnet(
    self, 'PublicSubnet2',
    vpc_id=self.vpc.vpc_id,
    cidr_block='10.0.2.0/24',
    map_public_ip_on_launch=True
)

route_table = ec2.CfnRouteTable(
    self, 'RouteTable',
    vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id
)

ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
    self, 'RTassoc1',
    subnet_id=pubsub1.ref,
    route_table_id=route_table.ref
)

ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
    self, 'RTassoc2',
    subnet_id=pubsub2.ref,
    route_table_id=route_table.ref
)

